# Parse a complex string for internationalization

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how to create meaningful error messages using the language class. What I would like to do is put a string into the language file that contains a PHP complex string and then parse it using the in scope variables.

For example, if the string in the languages file is;

```
"'${prompt_name}' must be at least ${min} characters long."
```

and the local variable are

```
$prompt_name = 'Test Prompt';
$min = 4;
```

The resulting string should be;

```
'Test Prompt' must be at least 4 characters long.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
sprintf("'%s' must be at least %d characters long.", $prompt_name, $min);
```